# PowerApps/Dynamics: Call an external library for data

Tags: azure, security, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-platform

I am working on a Power Component Framework (PCF) control that allows you to connect to an Azure Storage. The control will be later bound to a form, and I am using [Azure Storage JS (for browser) v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser) to connect to the resource.

My control works similarly to Azure Storage Explorer: I can upload, download files and navigate within containers.

I am concerned about the security of the solution, and mostly the connection to the storage.
The suggested way (in the library) is to expose a SAS Token to the Storage Account, and then pass a container name to connect to a specific container.

```
// Create a new BlobServiceClient
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);

// Create a unique name for the container by 
// appending the current time to the file name
const containerName = "container" + new Date().getTime();

// Get a container client from the BlobServiceClient
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
```

**As the PCF control is embedded within a form for entity in Dynamics, you can potentially stop the code execution in debugger and change the name of the container. Suddenly you are able to load to a totally different container than intended.**

Now, this is obviously pretty bad, and I would love to have a solution that is more secure.

The idea that I had was to move the Azure Storage operations to some backend, and within the control just make API calls to the service. However, this still doesn't make it any better, as I would still need to know the context of the entity within the form in order to connect to the correct container. For example, the user is editing account “john123”, and therefore he should only be able to connect to container “container-john123”.

I would also like to connect to navigate within the container, so from time to time, I would like to be able to request container data to be retrieved again from the PCF control.

Is there any way of doing this within Dynamics environment? I am quite new to the topic, and I have read a little about plugins, workflows etc., but I am not sure whether they are capable of responding to a "reload" operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate SAS tokens per container, that way, if someone alters their container name, it's no longer valid. You can also do some API management stuff or use child flows to make these things more transparent. But the topic your highlighting is sadly something that's a downside to most web applications nowadays.

Comment: unfortunately it seems that the container SAS token is actually not valid, and the SDK doesn't seem to be able to process it

Comment: The sas is just the key you should use to encrypt. If you use the SAS as you're access key, it won't work.